# Pass Array value to another viewcontroller and value show on label and change text on Button click

Tags: ios, textview, nsarray, tableview, uilocalnotification

```
`I am develop `IOS` App. Store data on Nsmutablearray using class object.and show the data on tableview and pass the data on next viewcontroller.On next viewcontroller get value for using class object app crash error msg is reason`: '-[ReligiousStatus objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b9f0100'
```

And also button click change the textview string value.the same error will be displayed

Please Give any help and Thanks in advance

```
//Code

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ViewStatusViewController *view = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewStatus"];

    view.array = [self.Data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //pass data to another view controller

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
}

//get value from second viewcontroller
 ReligiousStatus *sts = [_array objectAtIndex:0]; //Class name ReligiousStatus
    _textView.text = sts.status;

//button click change the textView value 

- (IBAction)next:(id)sender {
    NSInteger increment;
    increment++;

 //   NSMutableArray *arr    = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:_status.status];

    ReligiousStatus *sts = (ReligiousStatus *)[_array objectAtIndex:increment];
        _textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",sts.status];

    if (increment> sts.status.length) {


        _textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",sts.status];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure

```
[self.Data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

is Array and Contains Objects

before use it check if it contains objects

```
if(array.count) {

}
```